# Do scale applying approaches need to be the same for longitudinal invariance testing and the subsequent growth curve model?

Tags: time-series, structural-equation-modeling, growth-model, mplus, invariance

I have a question concerning scaling approaches in longitudinal invariance testing and
a subsequent latent growth curve.
That is, for example, if the invariance test was conducted with a marker indicator
approach, does the subsequent growth curve need to be also conducted with a marker
indicator approach.
My current case is that I did the invariance test with a fixed factor approach but
conducted my growth curve with a marker indicator (I've also tried effects coding)
approach since fixed factor doesn't work for growth curves.
My assumption is that if full invariance holds for strong invariance it does not
really matter but with partial invariance, it may be problematic because the
freed parameters also need to be freed in the growth model and if the approaches
differ, that is a bit tricky. (or is there a way to?)

So to summarize, my questions are,

1)Do scale applying approaches need to be the same for longitudinal invariance testing and the subsequent growth curve model?

2)Is there a way to test invariance with an effects coding approach? If so, it would be very very helpful if someone can point to me some coding examples on Mplus.

My second question is coming from the fact that for some reason, my data does not converge
with a marker indicator approach even for configural invariance. (It runs fine with a
fixed factor)

I'll post my codes bellow,

```
MODEL: !(Mplus) Model 1 Configural Longitudinal Invariance
!1)Factor loadings all freely estimated for each wave, not labeled
Time1 by t1ae1 t1ae2 t1ae3 t1ae5;
Time2 by t2ae1 t2ae2 t2ae3 t2ae5;
Time3 by t3ae1 t3ae2 t3ae3 t3ae5;
Time4 by t4ae1 t4ae2 t4ae3 t4ae5;
Time5 by t5ae1 t5ae2 t5ae3 t5ae5;
Time6 by t6ae1 t6ae2 t6ae3 t6ae5;
Time9 by t9ae1 t9ae2 t9ae3 t9ae5;

!2)Item intercepts (tau) all freely estimated except marker indicator, not labeled
[t1ae1-t9ae1@0]; 
[t1ae2-t9ae2]; 
[t1ae3-t9ae3];
[t1ae5-t9ae5];

! 3)item variances all freely estimated, not labeled
t1ae1-t9ae1; 
t1ae2-t9ae2; 
t1ae3-t9ae3;
t1ae5-t9ae5;
! 4)All Factor variance freely estimated 
Time1-Time9;
! 5)All Factor mean freely estimated
[Time1-Time9];

! 6)Factor covariances all freely estimated
Time1 Time2 Time3 Time4 Time5 Time6 Time9 with
Time1 Time2 Time3 Time4 Time5 Time6 Time9;

! 7)auto-correlated errors (item-specific)
t1ae1 with t2ae1 t3ae1 t4ae1 t5ae1 t6ae1 t9ae1;
t2ae1 with t3ae1 t4ae1 t5ae1 t6ae1 t9ae1;
t3ae1 with t4ae1 t5ae1 t6ae1 t9ae1;
t4ae1 with t5ae1 t6ae1 t9ae1;
t5ae1 with t6ae1 t9ae1;
t6ae1 with t9ae1;

t1ae2 with t2ae2 t3ae2 t4ae2 t5ae2 t6ae2 t9ae2;
t2ae2 with t3ae2 t4ae2 t5ae2 t6ae2 t9ae2;
t3ae2 with t4ae2 t5ae2 t6ae2 t9ae2;
t4ae2 with t5ae2 t6ae2 t9ae2;
t5ae2 with t6ae2 t9ae2;
t6ae2 with t9ae2;


t1ae3 with t2ae3 t3ae3 t4ae3 t5ae3 t6ae3 t9ae3;
t2ae3 with t3ae3 t4ae3 t5ae3 t6ae3 t9ae3;
t3ae3 with t4ae3 t5ae3 t6ae3 t9ae3;
t4ae3 with t5ae3 t6ae3 t9ae3;
t5ae3 with t6ae3 t9ae3;
t6ae3 with t9ae3;

t1ae5 with t2ae5 t3ae5 t4ae5 t5ae5 t6ae5 t9ae5;
t2ae5 with t3ae5 t4ae5 t5ae5 t6ae5 t9ae5;
t3ae5 with t4ae5 t5ae5 t6ae5 t9ae5;
t4ae5 with t5ae5 t6ae5 t9ae5;
t5ae5 with t6ae5 t9ae5;
t6ae5 with t9ae5;
```

I thank everyone who was kind enough to give me advice in advance.

Comment: By "fixed factor approach", do you mean you fixed the factor variances at each time point? If yes, then that is potentially problematic for longitudinal data since the factor variances may change across time. I would think that the most logical/consistent approach would be to use the same scaling method throughout. I don't see what advantage it would have to use different approaches for the longitudinal CFA vs. the growth model.

Comment: The marker indicator approach sometimes has (benign) convergence issues when the factor indicators are measured in very different metrics (when they have very different variances). Rescaling the indicators to a more similar metric or providing appropriate starting values for the loadings can help in that case.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I later did a read through of literature and asked Mplus support, too, but really did not get to a real answer on this. I ended up running it in a different scaling approach, which solved my problem. Your answers helped me take a different approach. Thank you again.